# Serial Port Reading with PHP weirdness

Tags: php, python, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I have a project already written in PHP.  I need to read data in from the serial port.  I would like to keep the ability to read from the serial port in the same language as the rest of the project.

I found a class that many people seem to be having problems with.  php_serial.class.php  Based on examples this is what I wrote for it as a test.  Using an RFID card reader as the serial input.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

// Include the class to read the serial line.
include ("php_serial.class.php");

// Let's start the class
$serial = new phpSerial;

$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyAMA0");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
// We can change the baud rate, parity, length, stop bits, flow control
#$serial->confFlowControl("none");

// Check if we can open the serial line.  Otherwise die.
if(!$serial->deviceOpen()) die("unable to open device");

stream_set_timeout($serial->_dHandle, 10);

$rfid_key = FALSE;

// Start the loop to keep checking the
while(!$rfid_key)
{
    $read = $serial->readPort();

    // Array to store eachvalue of the RFID tag
    $ascii_read  = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($read); $i++)
    {
        $ascii_read[] = ord($read[$i]);
        if(count($ascii_read) == 14 && $ascii_read[0] == 2 && $ascii_read[13] == 3)
        {
            $rfid_key = implode("", $ascii_read);
            break;
        }
    }

    // If the key is empty then sleep for 1 second.
    if(!$rfid_key)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
}

print_r($rfid_key);
print "\n\n";
```

If I run the script it will wait for an input, and if I flash an RFID tag over the antenna it fails.

I then decided to see if it was php or not, so I wrote a python script.

```
import serial
serialport = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, timeout=0.5)
response = serialport.readlines(None)
print response
```

If I put the tag on the antenna and run the script and then pull the tag away, I get whatever number of instances of the tag it read in that timespan.  Telling me that the RFID reader works with the RaspberryPi.

Now here's the really odd part.  If I go back and execute the php code after executing the python code then it works.  This leads me to believe that it has something to do with instantiation of the serial port done in Python that sticks around for the php code when it is executed afterwards.  I then strip down the python code to just instantiate the serial port and exit and as expected the php code works.

So, my question is.  WTF is python doing that the php code is not?  I am not an expert with the serial bus and am very confused atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the solution.  The problem is not the php script, but the options set for /dev/ttyAMA010

After much researching I found that running the command `/bin/stty -F /dev/ttyAMA010` showed me the current state of the serial line.  Running that after a fresh boot gave me this as the output.

```
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
```

Then running the python script to see what the differences were.

```
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
min = 0; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

I then systematically included each config option and refreshed my page until it worked.  In the end I discovered I needed 2 options in order to get the php serial script to work.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 -isig
stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 -icanon
```